# RichFaces rich:panel header not appearing

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I specified this

```
    <rich:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">
                Panel #1. Changing Style Synchronously
        </f:facet>
            Each component in the RichFaces has a pre-defined set of classes you can manipulate with. If defined, those
            classes overwrite the ones come from the skin.
    </rich:panel>
```

from the RichFaces demo, in my JSF page and no header appears, although I've nothing in my css which would interfere. What might be the reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: +1 as I am also seeing this in my app. They were working for a time, and then something changed. If I find that something I'll post the solution.

Comment: My problem was that I'd accidentally included the facet tags in the panel's form so they didn't have the panel as a direct parent. See below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont see any problem with using f:facet

Comment: As I have used the other way of doing it I unfortunately have no time to check this out in more detail, but for other readers you have decent rep saying it should work so I don't know what I did, but at least you also have a workaround.  Good karma gives the answer points to daedlus.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<f:facet name="header">
     <div><h:graphicImage value="/images/search.png" />
     <h:outputText value=" Action Logs Search" /></div>
    </f:facet>
```

in order to regenerate the error you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Mine disappeared when I accidentally included the panel's facets in the panel form. The facets must be children of the modal panel:

```
<rich:panel>
   <a4j:form> <!-- This is trouble! -->
     <f:facet name="header">
            Panel #1. Changing Style Synchronously
     </f:facet>
        Each component in the RichFaces has a pre-defined set of classes you can manipulate with. If defined, those
        classes overwrite the ones come from the skin.
   </a4j:form>
</rich:panel>
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, do please feel free to comment on why the f:facet tag is not working, but I get my nice shiny headers when I change the code so it's like this instead:

```
<rich:panel header="header">
            Each component in the RichFaces has a pre-defined set of classes you can manipulate with. If defined, those
            classes overwrite the ones come from the skin.
    </rich:panel>
```